# Ошибка NullPointer - не видит textview

Tags: android, textview

Добрый вечер! Не пойму в чем ошибка. В `OnCreate` я подключаю фрагмент, чтобы он сразу при запуске приложения открывался. В разметке фрагмента есть `textview` `selected_item`. По идеи приложение запускается: вставляется в фрейм фрагмент с разметкой и `textview`, далее находится этот textview и вставляется текст. Но почему-то ошибка `NullPointer`. Именно с текстом. Что не так?

```
Fragment frag1 = new Fragment1();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.frgmCont, frag1);
    ft.commit();
```

К тексту обращался и так:

```
 mSelectedItemView = (TextView)frag1.getView().findViewById(R.id.selected_item);
 mSelectedItemView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.selected_item),
           null, new MyHtmlTagHandler()));
```

И так:

```
mSelectedItemView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selected_item);
 mSelectedItemView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.selected_item),
           null, new MyHtmlTagHandler()));
```

класс фрагмента:

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, null);
}
}
```

Разметка фрагмента fragment2.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/selected_item2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Во фрагментах `getView()` возвращает `null` до момента вызова `onCreateView()` во фрагменте. `onCreateView()` вызывается после того, как вызвался `onCreate()`. Подробнее о фрагментах вы можете узнать в [документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).